# Reply from *VPN IP Address*: Destination host unreachable. Request timed out

Tags: networking, router, vpn, ip

I have a device attached to my Netgear router (recording device with an HDD).  The IP is the first in the below image:

[image]

I have a VPN IP set up for it.  The getter command for it returns VPN IP `10.31.1.125`.  The commands are sent using port `40943`.

These are the static routes I have (which I believe my current VPN IP is covered by at #3):

[image]

My Netgear router uses a static IP instead of a dynamic IP.  When I try to ping at the VPN IP, I get these results:

```
C:\>ping 10.31.1.125

Pinging 10.31.1.125 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 154.24.15.149: Destination host unreachable.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 10.31.1.125:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 1, Lost = 3 (75% loss),

C:\>
```

I don't understand why this isn't pinging correctly.  How can I fix it?  I'm a network newbie, so please let me know if you need any more info (or if I'm missing something really obvious).  Thank you.

***EDIT***:  I have another device attached to the router with a VPN IP.  I can successfully ping this VPN IP:

```
C:\>ping 10.25.64.12

Pinging 10.25.64.12 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.25.64.12: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.25.64.12: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.25.64.12: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=63
Reply from 10.25.64.12: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=63

Ping statistics for 10.25.64.12:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 5ms, Average = 3ms

C:\>
```

Comment: Am I correct in understanding that you're trying to ping your VPN IP from a non-VPN client?

Comment: @ernie My computer and my attached device are both connected to the same router.  Does that mean my computer is a non-VPN client?

Comment: Unless you're running the VPN software on your computer and have logged into the VPN, or your router is your VPN server (or maybe a client), then no, your computer is likely not on the VPN.

Comment: @ernie I have a camera attached to the router which I can successfully ping it's VPN IP.